# C++ language symbol separator

Tags: c++, parsing

I need to parse some c++ files to get some information out of it. One user case is I have a enum value "ID_XYZ", I want to find out how many times it appears in a source file. So my question is what are the separator dividing symbols in C++?

Comment: why don't you simple read the file to a string variable and then search for your required enum using basic string matching or regex based string search

Comment: Or what characters can appear in a variable name

Comment: It's all there in the standard

Comment: @leon, `Ranges of characters allowed [charname.allowed]
00A8, 00AA, 00AD, 00AF, 00B2-00B5, 00B7-00BA, 00BC-00BE, 00C0-00D6, 00D8-00F6, 00F8-00FF
0100-167F, 1681-180D, 180F-1FFF
200B-200D, 202A-202E, 203F-2040, 2054, 2060-206F
2070-218F, 2460-24FF, 2776-2793, 2C00-2DFF, 2E80-2FFF
3004-3007, 3021-302F, 3031-303F
3040-D7FF
F900-FD3D, FD40-FDCF, FDF0-FE44, FE47-FFFD
10000-1FFFD, 20000-2FFFD, 30000-3FFFD, 40000-4FFFD, 50000-5FFFD,
60000-6FFFD, 70000-7FFFD, 80000-8FFFD, 90000-9FFFD, A0000-AFFFD,
B0000-BFFFD, C0000-CFFFD, D0000-DFFFD, E0000-EFFFD` :)

Comment: Hi AurA, that's just an example, I may have ID_XYZ and ID_XYZZ, I don't want to mess up with both.

Comment: Those are the universal character names for identiﬁer
characters, and § 2.11 has `identiﬁer:
identiﬁer-nondigit
identiﬁer identiﬁer-nondigit
identiﬁer digit
identiﬁer-nondigit:
nondigit
universal-character-name
other implementation-deﬁned characters
nondigit: one of
a b c d e f g h i j k l m
n o p q r s t u v w x y z
A B C D E F G H I J K L M
N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z _
digit: one of
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9` I know the formatting's terrible, but it's a lot better right in the standard where I pulled it from.

Comment: You are probably best off either doing simple text search for `ID_XYZ` to be quick and dirty, or use a library if you need to be rigorous. Clang's modular source is probably the most popular. I have written another one available at http://code.google.com/p/c-plus .

Answer (score 2):

You can't really tokenize C or C++ source code based purely on separator characters -- you pretty much need to read in a character at a time, and figure out whether that character can be part of the current token or not.

Just for a couple of examples, when  you see a C-style begin-comment token, you need to look at characters until you encounter a close-comment token. Likewise, strings and pre-processor directives (e.g., `#if 0 .... #endif` sequences). To do it truly correctly, you also need to deal correctly with trigraphs. For example, consider something like this:

```
// Why doesn't this work??/
ID_XYZ = 1;
```

If the lexer doesn't handle trigraphs correctly, it will probably identify this as an instance of your `ID_XYZ` -- but in reality, it's not -- the `??/` at the end of the previous line is really a trigraph that resolves to `\`, which means the "single-line" comment actually extends to the end of the *next* line, and the apparent instance of `ID_XYZ` is really part of the comment.